# UILocalNotification es obsoleta en IOS10

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, push-notification

estoy trabajando en una app que genera notificaciones , sin embargo al generar una notificación en un dispositivo con versión igual o superior a 10 ; la notificación no es generada.
Como puedo cambiar el siguiente método para que funcione en todos los dispositivos

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
 {
     //mi procreso de notificaciones
 if (MOCA.initialized)
    {
        [MOCA handleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. Si lo que quieres es trabajar con notificaciones *PUSH* de un *APNS*, el método del delegate que estás utilizando no es el correcto.
2. Si lo que quieres, son notificaciones locales, en *iOS 10*, la librería `UILocalNotification` está obsoleta. Se utiliza la librería `UserNotifications`. Abajo te dejo un código que programa una notificación del usuario. Se acerca o se aleja de un punto geográfico concreto, espero que te sirva de referencia.
   Cuando programo esta notificación, ésta se muestra en pantalla y se lanza el método que comentas en tu pregunta.

   ```
   func createLocationNotifation(
       title: String,
       text: String,
       location: CLLocation,
       identifier: String,
       onExit: Bool
   ) {
       let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
           location.coordinate.latitude,
           location.coordinate.longitude
       )
       let region = CLCircularRegion(
           center: coordinate,
           radius: 100.0,
           identifier: identifier
       )
       region.notifyOnExit = onExit
       region.notifyOnEntry = !onExit

       let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)

       let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
       content.title = title
       content.body = text
       content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
       content.badge = 1

       let request = UNNotificationRequest(
           identifier: identifier,
           content: content,
           trigger: trigger
       )
       let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: Vale eso era lo que quería saber muchas gracias